# Poor drawing of CGGradient with alpha

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm ultimately trying to create a gradient overlay to fade from 60% black to clear, to 40% black. The result has a lot of banding, so I'm just trying to get two colours working properly first.

In this first case, I'm trying a gradient from solid black to solid white which draws pretty much perfectly.

[image: First case]

In the second case, I'm placing a gradient from 100% black to clear, against a solid gray background. The banding is really awful.

[image: Second case]

The code to make this gradient looks like this:

```
// Draw the overlay gradient
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

UIColor *firstColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:1.0];       
UIColor *secondColor = [UIColor clearColor];
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceAtop);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

NSArray *coreGraphicsColors = @[(id)firstColor.CGColor, (id)secondColor.CGColor];
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)coreGraphicsColors, 0);

static const CGFloat standardDegree = 270;
const CGFloat degree = (standardDegree * M_PI / 180);
const CGPoint center = CGPointMake(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
const CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(center.x - cos(degree) * size.width / 2, center.y - sin(degree) * size.height / 2);
const CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(center.x + cos(degree) * size.width / 2, center.y + sin(degree) * size.height / 2);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);

CGGradientRelease(gradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

Does anyone have some experience/tips with creating these gradients which are partly transparent? I've tried altering a few things like the positions and color space, all to no avail.

Comment: can you post a picture of what the result looks like?

Comment: @Fonix That code generates the second screenshot.

Comment: oh sorry, the pictures didnt want to load for me for some reason

Answer (score 0):

This might help you [AlphaGradientView](http://codingangry.com/index.php/site/article/ios_gradent_with_transparency/)